# Python-OpenCV cv2 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to learn contours in python using cv2.

I tried the following code given in a tutorial guide:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('C:\Users\Prashant\Desktop\test.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv2.drawContour(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Image1',img)
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3402
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   execfile(filename, namespace)
 File "C:/Users/Prashant/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 15, in <module>
   imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3402: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It says your input image should have 3 or 4 channels before applying the function `cv2.cvtColor`.

so check your image shape before applying the function by `print im.shape`. if the result is `None type` (most of the times, this is the problem), your image is not loaded correctly, most probably because your path is not correct.

The point is that your image should have 3 dimensions, `rows`, `columns` and `depth`.

Comment: @Abid Congrats for the golden [tag:opencv] badge.

Comment: Thank you @karlphillip. I thought you would need a friend to share the gold :)

Comment: changing the image isn't the case. If its a video file and you are trying to capture every frame and in some frames the shape is not found , then you shouldn't be changing the whole video file just because some frames didn't have proper shape attribute. Its better you handle it

Comment: Thanks it worked actually, the image was not loading properly.

Comment: What is the depth of an image ? Mine is load correctly but only have 2 channels ?

Answer (score 2):

1st print ret.
If it is showing false then your image is not taken properly.
If it is showing True Try this command - sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
Or in your /etc/modules file add bcm2835-v4l2 at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error on a raspberry PI with PI camera, try running this command first:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and couldn't find a solution, but on the web, it was working. My solution was almost funny - you can't have two streams. I turned off the web stream and then it was fine!