# opencv, python and RaspberryPi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have implemented this code on Raspberry-Pi module to read png images from a folder and convert it to gray, the code is as follows:

```
x = glob.glob("/home/pi/pngimages/ss*png")

for imagefile in x[0300:0302]:

 img = cv2.imread(imagefile)

 gray = cvt.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

but I get the following error:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3205 Traceback (most recent call last): File in  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Comment: Have you tried printing `imagefile` before the `imread`? Your glob call could return files of the form `sstextpng`. Probably best to make it `ss*.png` and retest.

Comment: x = glob.glob("/home/pi/png_images/ss*.png") for imagefile in x[0300:0302]:... this is what i use but what i could observe was cvt.cvtColor() function works for one image but when the loop runs for second image i get that error..?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this assertion happens if the image is `None`.  Try checking the image is being read properly first.

```
x = glob.glob("/home/pi/pngimages/ss*png")

for imagefile in x[0300:0302]:
    img = cv2.imread(imagefile)
    # You can do a print img.shape here if you want to see what's going on
    # If it returns NULL, something's wrong with your image or the path or something else
    if img:
        gray = cvt.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

If you find it doesn't do anything because img is `None`, check your directory and check that it's looking for the correct images

Have a look here as well: [Python-OpenCV cv2 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822288/python-opencv-cv2-opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4-in-unkno)