# Face detection errors in cv2

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

Lately I have been trying to write a simple program that can detect a face. I have never done this before so it was more of a warm up for me to get the hang of it. But I keep getting errors with every different sample I try. I have even copied samples straight off of the OpenCV website and I still got nothing but errors that don't make sense to me.

I copied my code exactly from this website
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0

and I am getting this error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Comment: It depends on the error. Please share the error for the code above.

Comment: I edited my question. I was having trouble putting the script up, so I just put up the website that I copied the script from and the error as well.

Comment: Looks like with this particular script your image is not the right kind to be calling the code on it that you are. Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822288/python-opencv-cv2-opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4-in-unkno

Comment: print img.channels before cvtColor please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the function "cvtColor", the image should be 3 or 4 channels.
For example:

1. This is to convert color image to gray image (src has 3 channels, but dst has 1 channel)

   cvtColor(src,dst,CV_BGR2GRAY);
2. This is to convert color from RGB to YCrCb space (src and dst both has 3 channels)

   cvtColor(src,dst,CV_BGR2YCrCb);