# what's wrong when i try to convert BGR to HSV and get error cvtColor?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

i have tried to convert image RGB to HSV using cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) code. But i get an error like this:[image: Error] and the code just like this : [image: code]

Anybody can help me please?
I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. It's impossible to copy and paste code from an image to reproduce the problem. It's just as easy to copy and paste the text and properly format it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-OpenCV cv2 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822288/python-opencv-cv2-opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4-in-unkno)

Comment: Don't use images, copy and paste the code, use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Check how many channels your image has after loading. It better be 3 or 4. If your image is RGB why are you using `BGR2HSV`?

Comment: test whether the image was loaded successfully before using it.

Comment: Ensure you are not including a 0 at the end of your 'cv2.imread', that converts the image to grayscale. Also make sure your file is in the location specified, and of the format specified.

Answer (score 0):

`cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` expects an image with 3 channels, your image tensor probably doesn't have 3 channels.

You can check that by printing `image.shape`.

P.S. You shouldn't post/error msgs with images. It is not good for other people searching for similar problems (SEO).